# pdflatex --enable-write18 autopp.pdf

Tags: pdftex, miktex, emacs, shell-escape, auto-pst-pdf

running `pdflatex --enable-write18 myfile.tex` under emacs+MikTeX works, but, generates a `myfile-autopp.pdf` with the graphic and doesn't include it to the `myfile.pdf`.

How to get the graphic inside the original document?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book} 
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot,pst-text,pst-tree,pst-eps,
  pst-‌​fill,pst-node,pst-ma‌​th} 
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{pspicture} 
\psframe*[linecolor=blue](10,10) 
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

[SOLVED] : 
1°) Close Emacs (handle on MiKTeX file system) ;
2°) Update MiKTeX (several times, until up to date) ;
3°) Add "[crop=off]" option to "auto-pst-pdf" package, as proposed by @Herbert ;
4°) Recompile : (with Emacs) 
   a) "M-x compile"
   b) "pdflatex --enable-write18 myfile.tex"

---

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a full compilable code?

Comment: sure : \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot,pst-text,pst-tree,pst-eps,pst-fill,pst-node,pst-math}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document} 
\begin{pspicture}
\psframe*[linecolor=blue](10,10)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}

Comment: I have no problem with this code. Did you really launch the compiler with the switch `--enable-write18`? Does it work from the command line?

Comment: @Bernard from the command line : "M-x compile", then "pdflatex --enable-write18 myfile.tex". but MiKTeX wasn't up to date : emacs had a handle in it's file system... retrying

Comment: @Bernard it's solved : emacs had a handle on MiKTeX that prevented the updates... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A missing image is often a missing Perl installation which is needed for `pdfcrop`. In such a case use

```
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
```

Comment: [crop=off] leads to the "! Undefined control sequence.
\Gin@setfile ...Gin@page \@empty \else (\Gin@page 
                                                  )\fi }
l.6 \psframe
            *[linecolor=blue](10,10)
? " error

Comment: I cannot see it with up-to-date TeXLive2017. Is your MikTeX up-to-date?

Comment: update "Unsuccesful" ; "permission denied: path=c:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\df2c24cb21984fa85003c1ecc818ff83.fndb"

Comment: @user140297: did you install MikTeX as User or admin?

Comment: @Herbert as user... trying to update after closing emacs, maybe it had a handle, then reinstalling miktek.

Comment: @Herbert emacs had a handle on a directory, Miktek update worked... retrying

Comment: @Herbert it's solved : the handle from emacs prevented MiKTeX to update...